# Does probability of a derangement go up under passing to subgroups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics, permutation-groups

This is prompted by my attempts to work on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102751/a-mixing-property-for-finite-fields-of-characteristic-2/). Let $H \subset G \subseteq S_d$ be transitive permutation groups. Recall that an element of $S_d$ is called a derangement if it has no fixed points.

> Is the proportion of derangements in
>   $H$ always greater than in $G$?

If $H$ doesn't have to be transitive, then the answer is "no"; just let $H$ be trivial. But a quick sampling of examples with $G$ and $H$ both transitive doesn't turn up any counterexamples.

**UPDATE** Never mind. $A_4$ inside $S_4$, the probability of a derangement goes down from $3/8$ to $1/4$.

Comment: I'm voting to close as no longer relevant, because, if I understand the MO software correctly, if the question remains open and (as I would expect) no answers (in the sense of the software) are given, then the question will keep reappearing on the front page from time to time.

Comment: @Andreas Blass: I do not think this is the case. I never saw a question *without* an answer reappear just so. Those that reappear are those *with* answer(s) that are *still* in the 'unanswered' category, i.e. no accept answer and none with positive (or perhaps +2) score. (I once spend some time to check ca 2000 items in unanswered category looking for each question modified by the MO-user, ie having been bumped; very few have *no* answer *and* for a couple of those that *currently* have none I checked, with kind help of Felipe Voloch, that they *used to have* one.) 